# Create a dummy sound file?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a constant error while running Minecraft that is a side effect of a mod I use to mute the music on the starting menu screen. This error will occur in random intervals from 5–30 seconds. The error is:

```
Unable to play unknown soundEvent: minecraft:none
```

Now from what I understand I should be able to create a blank sound file somewhere so that this error will stop happening, but I need to know:

1. Where to put this sound file (Resourcepack? Assets? etc.)
2. What format the file should be in (.ogg, .mp3, etc.)

To be honest this is all just an educated guess. If there is a better way to fix this issue, please let me know.

Comment: What's "the way I mute some sounds"?

Comment: @vpzomtrrfrt I have a mod installed to mute the music on the homescreen

Comment: Where is this error showing up? Is it just in the log files or is it constantly filling your chat? (And is there a reason you can't submit it as a bug to the mod maker?)

Comment: Not sure what mod is doing it is the problem, have over 200 installed, and it's just in the logs @SevenSidedDie

Comment: From looking at this [thread](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php?topic=15189.0), it seems like minecraft can't find your 'none' sound file. Unfortunately, I have no experience with modding minecraft, so I don't know the appropriate folder structure/file location.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this error is actually harmless, just like many during startup that are due to mods having images at odd sizes.

**NOTICE:** Untested, but I assume it "might" work. If it doesn't, might need to have a mod that allows adding to the string table.

If you look at how a resource pack adds sounds (and how command blocks play a sound), you can do it that way. Probably having it named `none.ogg` will be good. Would need to be placing it where the sounds base would be at in the resource folder.

Example: If a sound to replace a built-in minecraft sound via. a command block is placed, according to what it shows for the command block syntax at, `a/b/c/d.ogg` in the modpack, you would place your dummy in the same folder that `a` is in for this example.

Random tidbit: the `.ogg` file type is a free sound "container" format (`.mp3` is similar but is covered by licenses that require the devs to have paid for to include the `.mp3` file format to be allowed to be used in their products).